# Identify Richtek chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I am repairing a HP Elitebook 745 and found that the 3.3V and 5V rails are not working.
My idea was to replace the buck converter ICs, but I can't figure out what the part numbers are. The ICs have the following markings:

4W=2H

3B=2F

I figured out that these are Richtek ICs but don't get any further than that...

Here is a picture of the package:

[image: Picture of the Richtek ICs.]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is it too much to ask to crop and rotate images so they are more useful?

Comment: Not working does not mean they are broken or needs replacing - something upstream may prevent these from turning on, or there may be a short circuit downstream.

Comment: Many websites less reputable than this one can be found offering schematics, for free, by punching the model name and “schematics” into google. I did this for you and a very brief survey of the results seems promising.

Comment: Are you sure the marking of the left one is `4W=` ? As far as I can tell there is no Richtek part with that marking and package.

Comment: @Bryan I searched for hours for the schematics, but I can't find them. All websites showing up in google are all the same type of forum where you need to pay to do anything.

Comment: @Justme The LDO on one of the converters doesn't power up. I suspect that one to be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one marked `3B=` is a [Richtek RT7290A](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT7290A/DS7290A-04.pdf) buck converter.

[image]

There is no Richtek device in a UQFN-16L package with a `4W=` marking. However, there is one with `4M=`, the [Richtek RT7291BGQUF](https://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT7291A=RT7291B/DS7291AB-04.pdf) and it's a 5V buck converter. So I think you misread the markings on the left part. It's not clearly readable in the picture, but to me it looks more like `4M`.

[image]

Comment: The marking is indeed 4M=. Thanks a lot for helping me out so quickly!